# Android: Unable to save more than the number 195 in a file

Tags: java, android, file, byte, storage

For my Game, I store the number of games that have been played by a user in a file on the internal storage. This works perfectly up-till the number 195 is stored after which regardless of the number of games played, it does not increase at all.

```
public void saveNumGames(){
    Log.d("saveNumGames", "Called");
    int numGames;
    File numGamesFile = new File(mainActivity.getFilesDir(), "numGames");
    try {

        BufferedInputStream BIS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(numGamesFile));
        numGames = BIS.read();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        numGames = 0;
    }
    try{
        numGames++;
        Log.d("numGames", Integer.toString(numGames));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(numGamesFile);
        PrintWriter PW = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
        PW.write(numGames);
        PW.flush();
        PW.close();
        if(numGames==12){
            Games.Achievements.unlock(MainActivity.apiClient, "CgkIlcXhyp4YEAIQDA");
        } else if(numGames==50){
            Games.Achievements.unlock(MainActivity.apiClient, "CgkIlcXhyp4YEAIQDQ");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My thought process is that this is caused by the number 195 being the maximum value storable in a byte(or bit?). If so, what should I do to prevent this number cap from occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you use two method wrong.First is numGames = BIS.read(); method read() designed for read only one byte. Another method PW.write(numGames) method write which parameter is int specifying a character to be written. 
It should work :

```
  public static void saveNumGames() {
    Log.d("saveNumGames", "Called");
    int numGames;
    File numGamesFile = new File(mainActivity.getFilesDir(), "numGames");
    try {
        numGames = new Integer(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(mainActivity.getFilesDir() + "numGames"))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        numGames = 0;
    }

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(numGamesFile)) {
        numGames++;
        Log.d("numGames", Integer.toString(numGames));
        PrintWriter PW = new PrintWriter(fos);
        PW.write(String.valueOf(numGames));
        PW.flush();
        PW.close();
        if (numGames == 12) {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(MainActivity.apiClient, "CgkIlcXhyp4YEAIQDA");
        } else if (numGames == 50) {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(MainActivity.apiClient, "CgkIlcXhyp4YEAIQDQ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve I would use the SharedPrefereces class ( [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref))

[Saving key-value](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)  is example usage of this

Answer (score 0):

One Byte is 8 bits so you will certainly need more than that to store anything like 195. I would be interested in knowing the following when 196 is stored in the file.

what is the value of numGames after this line

`numGames = BIS.read();`

what does this print

`Log.d("numGames", Integer.toString(numGames));`